# Looping through a list in chunks

Tags: r, loops, yahoo-finance

I have a list of several thousand stock symbols to pass through a function. However the function only accepts 200 or less symbols at a time. How do i set up the loops to pass through chunks of 200 symbols until the list is complete. Below is some loose structure i think it may look like. The function works when I pass through the manually shortened shortsymb, but I need to automate this process so it can iterate.

```
library(quantmod)
symbols<-read.csv("companylist.csv")

for(i in 1:end){
  for(i in 1:200)

      metrics <- getQuote(paste(symbols sep="", collapse=";"), what=what_metrics)
}}

shortsymb<-symbols[1:199,]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible quick'n'dirty solution:

```
nSym <- nrow(symbols)
chunkSize <- 200
for(i in 1:ceiling(nSym / chunkSize)){  
  shortsymb<-symbols[((i-1)*chunkSize+1):min(nSym,(i*chunkSize)),]
  # do what you need with shortsymb
}
```

Description of the code:

- compute the number of chunks by simply dividing: `nSym / chunkSize` (we take the ceiling since there can be a remainder, if `nSym` is not multiple of `chunkSize`)
- for each chunk `(1,2,...,n)` we compute the corresponding start and end row indexes, as `start = ((i-1)*chunkSize+1)` and `end = min(nSym,(i*chunkSize))` (`min` function is necessary because last chunk might be smaller than `chunkSize`)
- we use the indexes to subset the original `data.frame`

Comment: quick and dirty works for me, clever solution, thanks

Comment: @digEmAll you have an extra parentheses that is not needed at the very end!